# Bootstrap - Border On Columns With Gutter

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid, border

I'm trying to have 4 divs which are 3 columns each in width, with a border of 3px. I've got the columns in fine with the border, but I can't get border-box to work. I'm assuming that I need the border to be an inner border to allow the gutter between each div.

I'm trying to do the same thing with 2, 6 column divs and having the same issue.

```
<div class="container products">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- First featured product -->
        <div class="col-lg-6 featured_product">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6"><img src="img/products/xbo_hs.png" alt=""></div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-push-1">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
                        <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
                        <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
                        <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
                        <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
                        <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
                    </ul>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">More Info</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- End first featured product -->

        <!-- Second featured product -->
        <div class="col-lg-6 featured_product">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6"><img src="img/products/xbo_hs.png" alt=""></div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-push-1">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
                        <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
                        <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
                        <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
                        <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
                        <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
                    </ul>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">More Info</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- End second featured product -->
    </div>

.products {
   padding-top: 30px;

  .featured_product {
      border: 5px solid #1488c8;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;

      ul {
         list-style-type: disc;
         padding-top: 5%;
         padding-bottom: 5%;
      }

      button {
        width: 100%;
      }
}
```

Comment: where is your code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap has the box-sizing property set to border-box by default so no need to apply it to anything.

**From BS:**

```
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Box-sizing takes the padding and border as part of the elements height and width. 
Gutters in bootstrap are created using padding, so applying a border to a column won't achieve what you are looking for.

Why don't you create an `.inner` and apply the border to that...

```css
.inner{
  background: aliceblue;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="inner">col-6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="inner">col-6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I've tried this but the inner box doesn't wrap for some reason. It seems to have no height

Comment: I don't follow, here is a pen with your code and the inner concept applied... the height seems fine to me. Is this not right...? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGWqqK

Comment: That works perfectly, I must have had some sort of mistake in my css. Thank you so much.

Comment: I did notice that your .products scss/sass  tag was not closed properly, maybe that was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In your `css`, you are nesting `tags`. I don't know what you are trying to achieve with that but I believe this is what you want to do:

```
.products{
   padding-top: 30px;
}
.featured_product{
    border: 5px solid #1488c8;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
.featured_product ul{
    list-style-type: disc;
    padding-top: 5%;
    padding-bottom: 5%;
}

.featured_product button{
    width: 100%;
}
```

### [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/nvonog3x/2/)

Comment: Sorry, I should have said. I'm using sass.